# Generator Expression vs yield: Why isn't 'next()' working?

Tags: python

I know I must be missing something simple, but I am not seeing it.

If I have a generator expression like this:

```
>>> serializer=(sn for sn in xrange(0,sys.maxint))
```

I can generate, easily, individual integers like this:

```
>>> serializer.next()
0
>>> serializer.next()
1
>>> serializer.next()
2
```

If I write a generator like this:

```
>>> def ser():
...    for sn in xrange(0,100000):
...       yield sn
```

It is no bueno:

```
>>> ser().next()
0
>>> ser().next()
0
>>> ser().next()
0
```

???  What am I missing ???

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`ser()` creates the generator. So each time you call `ser()` it is sending you a new generator instance.  You need to use it just like the expression:

```
serializer = ser()
serializer.next()
```

Consider that, if it *didn't* work this way, you could only ever use the `ser()` function once and you could never reset it.  Plus, you can change the ser function to accept a max integer, and make your program more flexible.

```
def ser(n=sys.maxint):
    for sn in xrange(0, n):
        yield sn
```

Comment: no problem. it's definitely non-obvious, since the other major type of functions that do this (decorators) have an explicit `return wrapper` in them, which I guess is implicit/magically created by the `yield` statement :P

Answer (score 5):

In your second example you keep creating a new instance, starting with a fresh generator.

```
g = ser()
g.next()
g.next()
```

Create the generator once and reuse it.

Answer (score 4):

```
ser()
```

initializes a **new** generator each time.

To fix it do something like this:

```
s = ser()
next(s) # next is preferred over .next which is why .next has been removed in Py3
next(s)
```